# User getting permission denied when trying to send mail as other user

Tags: permissions, exchange

I have a general shared mailbox setup within my organization that takes in mail from new applicants.  Our recruiter who has full access to this mailbox which is attached to her own can receive messages but if she tries to reply or forward one that came in this mailbox she gets the following error.

The following recipient(s) could not be reached:

```
  <Firstname> <Lastname> on 2/17/2011 9:34 AM
        You do not have permission to send to this recipient.  For assistance, contact your system administrator.
        MSEXCH:MSExchangeIS:/DC=ENT/DC=domain:domainname
```

Now I have gone in Active Directory and given her full access to that mailbox through Exchange Advanced Features as well as set the exchange server to allow relaying from all.

I can attach the mailbox to my own administrator account and can send just fine doing the same thing she does it works.

At my wits end here.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding her as a delegate for the shared mailbox.

Comment: It's the easy overlooked things that are normally the right ones.  Thank you so much for pointing that out.  It's now working.

Comment: @CRodgers.  Yeah, that one's bitten me before.  Glad it's working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't "You do not have permission to send to this recipient" clearly indicate that the problem is the receiving recipients mail address, not the sender's? I've never worked with Exchange, but judging from the error message I'd spontaneously say a server doesn't allow relaying for the used domain.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q284204 and discussion on http://forums.msexchange.org/You_do_not_have_permission_to_send_to_this_recipient/m_180147400/tm.htm might be of help.

Comment: Relaying was setup as I stated in my original question but this was resolved by just adding the user as a delegate.